# Как вывести массив в цикле с помощью метода map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Сижу разбираюсь с реактом, столкнулась с такой задачей как вывод массива через метод map в react. Пример массива :[1,2,3,4,5,6]

P.S. Не нужно писать про документацию. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот зря вы не читаете доку https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Если все таки документация не для вас, то результаты гугулятся так: `react list render`

```
const myawesomearray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
{myawesomearray.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
```

Пример на [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-water-pxb14)

Comment: Только не нужно использовать индекс как ключ - это bad practice.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, согласен но в данном примере это будет вполне приемлемо, так как список всего один. В других же случаях нужно использовать что-то уникальное.

Comment: Нормально до тех пор, пока в списке не меняется число элементов.